# factory girl rails traits for model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to setup my factory girl that when I passed in `create(:user, :admin)`, it will create a user and add a record in the Role model/table. My association is that, User has_one Role, Role belongs_to User

This is the setup of my factory girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name                   "Test User"
    email                  "test_user@serviceseeking.com.au"
    contact_phone          "0412345678"
    password               "123123"
    password_confirmation  "123123"
    skip_email_validation  true

    trait :as_admin do
      factory(:role) { name  "Untouchable" }
    end

  end
end
```

But for some reason, it doesn't create the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What errors are you getting?

I think you should be getting an error saying that there is no trait called `:admin`. If you want to create admin users with a call to `create(:user, :admin)` your trait must be named `:admin`.

Secondly I also think that what you want to do inside the `:admin` trait is this:

```
trait :admin do
  role name: "Untouchable"
end
```

If you have your association set up and a factory for `Role` called `:role` this should create a `Role` record with the name `"Untouchable"` and associate it with your user.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The as_admin/admin part was just a mistake. Thanks for the answer, this is what I needed. I'm having a hard time with the test setup rather than the tests themselves XD

Comment: Hi, can I ask a follow up question? I actually modified your answer to make it work, instead of `role name: "Untouchable"` I just put `role` inside the trait method. So my question is, I want to make you code work since my Role factory has a default "name" setup, and what I want is, if i called the :admin trait of user, it would overwrite the "name" of the role to "Untouchable". When I tried your  answer im getting an error `Role(#108171720) expected, got Hash`

Comment: Oh sorry, you can't pass options to implicit associations like that. If you try `association :role, name: "Untouchable"` instead of `role name: "Untouchable"`?